# Modify code to convert it to a list, and add the charachter # between each value, using only 1 function, no new parameters

Tags: python

What I have now:

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
out = []
if start == stop:
    print(start)
elif stop > start:
    print(start)
    print_numbers(start + 1,stop)
elif stop < start:
    a = print(start)
    b = print_numbers(start - 1,stop)
```

I want to change the output to be in list form with # in between each value

ex:
def print_numbers(1,3) would be = 1, #, 2, #, 3

Other try:

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
out = []
if start == stop:
    (start)
elif stop > start:
    out.append((start))
    out.append(print_numbers(start + 1,stop))
    return out
elif stop < start:
    out.append((start))
    out.append(print_numbers(start - 1,stop))
    return out
```

Comment: Yes, I tried but it will not work

Comment: Show us specifically what code you wrote in order to "try" that, and show exactly what happened when it "didn't work"

Comment: I added it to original question

Comment: `out.append(print(start))` should be just `out.append(start)`.

Comment: Output looks like : [1, [2, None]]

Comment: Oh, right, you would need to `.extend` instead. But really, did you consider using a loop rather than recursion?

Comment: Recursion is required

Comment: If this is for a homework assignment, then you should explicitly say so, and also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Otherwise, I can very confidently assure you that recursion is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
    result = []
    for n in range(start,stop+1):
        result.append(n)
        if n < stop:
            result.append("#")
    return result
    
print_numbers(1,3)
```

output : [1, '#', 2, '#', 3]

Using recursion:

```
def print_result(start,stop):
    return [start] + ["#"] + print_result(start+1,stop) if start < stop else [start]
print_result(1,3)
```

Comment: Can't use for, must be recursion

Comment: You didn't mention that before. Try the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
    x = list(range(start,stop+1))
    new = []
    for e in x:
        new.append(e)
        new.append('-')
    return new
print(print_numbers(1,3))
```

Or this could work.

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
    x = list(range(start,stop+1))
    for i in range(len(range(start,stop+1))-1,0,-1):x[i:i] = '#'
    return x
print(print_numbers(1,3))
```

Comment: Can't use for, must be recursion

Comment: No where do you state that in your question but ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
func = lambda x,y: [int(d/2) if i % 2 == 0 else "#" for i, d in enumerate(range(x*2,((y+1)*2)-1))]
```

Comment: Can't use for, must be recursion

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
def print_numbers(start,stop):
  out=[]
  if start==stop:
    return start
  else:
    out.append(start)
  out.append('#')
  try:
    return(out+print_numbers(start+1,stop))
  except TypeError:
    return(out+[print_numbers(start+1,stop)])
```